# Jasmine js: Add source method for test execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I have as simple "hello world" project and I want to test the famous hélloWorld function.

The project is structured like this:

```
├── package.json
├── spec
│   ├── helloWorldSpec.js
│   └── support
│       └── jasmine.json
└── src
    └── helloWorld.js
```

And the file content:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "jasmineTest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "jasmine": "~2.1.0"
  }
}
```

**spec/helloWorldSpec.js**

```
// var helloWorld = require('../src/helloWorld.js');
describe('Test', function() {
    it('it', function() {
        helloWorld();
    });
});
```

**src/helloWorld.js**

```
function helloWorld() {
    return "Hello world!";
}
// module.exports = helloWorld;
```

**spec/support/jasmine.json**

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

***My problem:***

When I run `npm install` jasmine is downloaded.
=> ok

When I run `./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js`
I have the error `ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined  ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined`

***My Question:***

How can I access the method helloWord contained in `src/helloWorld.js` in the test scope without using module.exports = xxx.

Comment: Strange that jasmine website doesn't say where to give the path to the code that's being tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Create a **GruntFile.js** containing:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      jasmine: {
        src: ['src/**/*.js'],
        options: {
          specs: ['spec/**/*Spec.js'],
          vendor: []
        }
      }
    });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
};
```

Update **package.json** with *[grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)*, *[grunt-cli](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli)* and *[grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine)* dependencies

```
{
  "name": "jasmineTest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "jasmine": "~2.1.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Update npm dependencies:

```
npm update
```

And relaunch test using grunt and not directly jasmine:

```
./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt jasmine
```

And you got:

```
Running "jasmine:src" (jasmine) task
Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS

 Test
   - it...
log: Spec 'Test it' has no expectations.
   ✓ it

1 spec in 0.008s.
>> 0 failures
```

Done, without errors.

Comment: please share your gruntfile.js

Comment: @Eugene Krevenets: missing gruntfile.js is now shared.

Answer (score 1):

According to Jasmine staff :

> You don't need to specify your source files in the config - just require them in from your spec files.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/49

But then, you do need to use export. 
This is not a Jasmine issue but vanilla Javascript. You want to call a method from another file so you need to export and require it. 
Why don't you want to ?