# How to set source files in jasmine.json with Jasmine 2

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, mocha.js

I've found Jasmine 2.4's page on [testing node.js files](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/node.html), and it even mentions setting the spec **and source** files in the spec/support/jasmine.json file. But neither the online examples **nor** the `jasmine examples` show anything on how to tell jasmine where to find the source files.

So I keep getting ReferenceErrors because it doesn't seem to be reading in my source files. It should be noted that for now I'm just using this to teach some students about testing, and using their single-file toy projects for practice. (Like a CLI Hangman Game, that sort of thing.) So for now there's no module.exports going on, although some of their projects to use `require()` to bring in third-party modules. I was using Karma until I realized that's only supposed to be for browser JavaScript, and `require` kept failing.

**Edit:** I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154475/jasmine-js-add-source-method-for-test-execution?rq=1) that is asking basically the same thing, but I don't want to use grunt just to make Jasmine read in a source file. Seems like something that should be built in, like how Karma asks for where your source and spec files are.

**Second Edit:** I shouldn't have to put this here, but Emarco marked my question as a duplicate of the one I linked in my first edit above, *even though I very specifically explained why that other post doesn't answer my question.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine js: Add source method for test execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154475/jasmine-js-add-source-method-for-test-execution)

Comment: Clearly you didn't read my whole post @Emarco. I had even specifically already mentioned why the post you referred to doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Well, I did read the post and gave an answer but since I was giving almost the same answer for the other question, it was deleted by a moderator and I was asked to flag this one as duplicate (I understand that the validated answer of the other question doesn't help you, it didn't help me neither, but as you say in your edit the problem is the same in both case, I wonder if there is a special way to handle this situation)

Answer (score 6):

FWIW I've found that listing my source files in the `helpers` list works..

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "fooSpec.js",
    "barSpec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "../src/foo.js",
    "../src/bar.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: With Jasmine 2? It doesn't work for me. Do you have an online running example?

Comment: It works and follows from a documentation: 
_Array of filepaths (and globs) relative spec_dir to include before jasmine specs_

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the jasmine developers seem to rely on grunt or other tools to use jasmine. As you already mentioned, the only way to make it work without grunt or karma is to use require.js.

Put the require.js file from [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) in your index.html .

Just require the source file you have in the corrosponding spec.js file like so:

```
//Be careful to choose the right path from the sight of your spec.js    
var helloworld = require('../src/helloworld'); //the actual filename without '.js'
```

Then export your script within the "helloworld.js" like so:

```
exports.helloWorld = function(){
    return "Hello world!";
};
```

That worked for me ... i hope that helps, did'nt find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

In jasmine v3.3.1 , my below code is working and tested with Protractor too.
All we have to do is define data source location.

```
//My script is in src/com/sam/scripts so I go back to root
var jsondataobj = require('../../../../config/Jsoninput.json');//define  the data source location
describe('spec with 2 specs it mean a spec so here are 2 specs', function() {   


      it('stackoverflow login check', function() {

        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

        browser.driver.get(jsondataobj.testsiteurl);
           console.log("Test site URL is : "+jsondataobj.testsiteurl);
           element(by.id(jsondataobj.locators.loginpage.username)).sendKeys(jsondataobj.credentials.username1);


      });

})
```

My data source a .json file which is in config folder . Exact file as per the below .

```
{

  "testsiteurl":"https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f",

  "locators":{
    "loginpage":{
      "username":"email",
      "password":"password"
    }
  },

  "credentials":{

    "username1":"stack@over.com",
    "password1":"donjoeweclome"

  }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

On your `spec/support/jasmine.json` file, you need to have and object, with an `spec_dir` and `spec_files` atributes.

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "fooSpec.js",
    "barSpec.js"
  ]
}
```

jasmine will use the `spec_dir` to prefix your `spec_files` items and run the tests. For a fooSpec.js, when you run `jasmine` on the BASE_DIR for you project, the tests are going to run for `BASE_DIR/spec/fooSpec.js` and `BASE_DIR/spec/barSpec.js`

Comment: Not only have you not answered OP's question, but you've also answered the part that the OP knows about and specifically does not want.